# Disable XAML Preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, xaml

In Visual Studio 2008 when I open a XAML file from the project it displays the horizontal split with the preview on the top, and the XAML on the bottom.  Most of the time our XAML won't render in the preview, so I just have to wait for it to try to render, and then close the preview.

Is there a way to have it default to not showing the XAML Preview window and just giving me a full XAML edit window?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the VS2008 menu select **tools**, **options** to display the options dialog. Then from the treeview in the dialog select **text editor**, **xaml**, **miscellaneous** then check the **always open documents in full XAML view** in the right pane.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  That works perfectly.  I thought I had looked there but I guess I missed it.  So much faster now.

Answer (score 1):

It was supposed to be removed with the release of the tools for Silverlight 3, but it's still there, it's just hidden by default. This saves having to close it at least, but doesn't fix the performance problems that are the heart of the matter.