# No WPF designer in VS2013 Pro

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently running Visual Studio 2013, and I can't access the WPF Designer because it doesn't show. I tried reinstalling VS2013 and when I did "repair" I had the VS2013 update 1 installer crash for no reason.

Everytime I try to update with the first update it just crashs. How can I do a clean uninstall and a clean install ?

I'm running Windows 8 64bits.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you by accident have disabled it?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224774/disable-xaml-preview

Comment: I don't have an entry about XAML in my settings.

Answer (score 4):

You can find it here, I dont think it is a problem with VS13

[image]

Comment: That doesn't do anything while I'm on a .xaml file. When I right click a .xaml file in the solution explorer I don't have any option to open the designer (even with "Open with").